# Property 'Azure' does not exist on type 'Transports' for winston

Tags: node.js, winston, azure-blob-storage

```
    var winston = require("winston");
    require("winston-azure-blob-transport"); 
    var logger = new (winston.Logger)({
        transports: [
            new (winston.transports.AzureBlob)({
                account: {
                    name: "Azure storage account sub domain ([A-Za-z0-9])",
                    key: "The long Azure storage secret key"
                },
                containerName: "A container name",
                blobName: "The name of the blob",
                level: "info"
            })
        ]
    });
    logger.warn("Hello!");
```

I get an error that Property 'Azure' does not exist on type 'Transports'

Comment: Did you install winston-azure-blob-transport using `npm install winston-azure-blob-transport` ?

Comment: yes i had installed it

Comment: Which version of Winston are you using? Can you please provide your package.json?

Comment: "winston": "^2.4.0",
    "winston-azure-blob-transport": "^0.2.6",
    "winston-daily-rotate-file": "^1.7.2",
    "winston-express-middleware": "^0.1.0"

Answer (score 0):

I still cannot reproduce this issue with the code you provided.

Here is my `package.json` file:

```
{
  "name": "testwinston",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "winston": "^2.4.0",
    "winston-azure-blob-transport": "^0.2.6",
    "winston-daily-rotate-file": "^1.7.2", 
    "winston-express-middleware": "^0.1.0"
  }
}
```

This is the code I am using:

```
var winston = require("winston");
require("winston-azure-blob-transport"); 

var logger = new (winston.Logger)({
    transports: [
        new (winston.transports.AzureBlob)({
            account: {
                name: "<my storage account name>",
                key: "my account key"
            },
            containerName: "test-container",
            blobName: "testlog.txt",
            level: "info"
        })
    ]
});
logger.warn("Hello!");
```

Then a blob file would be created with the following content:

[image]

Comment: I'm also able to create files in blob storage but I'm working with typescript I'm getting error with ts that [ts] Property 'AzureBlob' does not exist on type 'Transports'.
I'm sorry for not mentioning before.